# I want remove scroll mode from Navigation Drawer Android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

[i want remove this space from navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd1bZ.jpg)

I want remove scroll mode from Navigation Drawer or any solution for create custom navigation drawer without menu

Here is my layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

        <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_live"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_live"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Creating a truly custom NavDrawer is possible, with little tweaking to the components.

Here are the steps:

**1 - No menu layout, just `headerView`**

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view_end"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-64dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/shop_list"
    />
```

Notice that i placed margin start and left to -64dp. That's to get the drawer layout to be full width.

**2 - Disable NavigationMenuView's scroll**

Even though we didn't put a menu layout, it's still created and we need to access it and disable the scroll. Because this view is instance of the RecyclerView, we just need to override it's layout manager and disable the vertical scroll.

```
private fun disableMenuScroll(navView: NavigationView) {
    val navMenu = navView.getChildAt(0) as NavigationMenuView
    navMenu.layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this) {
        override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

**3 - Set the header layout to be full height**

Here we use reflection to get the `presenter` from `HeaderView` and from that presenter we get the `LinearLayout` that holds our headerLayout. That `LinearLayout` is the one that doesn't let our layout stretch to match parent. We just change the `LayoutParams` for that LinearLayout and it's done.

```
private fun changeDrawerLayoutHeight(navView: NavigationView) {

    /*With reflection get the navView's presenter*/
    val field = navView.javaClass.getDeclaredField("presenter")
    field.isAccessible = true

    val presenter = field.get(navView) as NavigationMenuPresenter

    /*From presenter, get the header layout field*/
    val layoutField = presenter.javaClass.getDeclaredField("headerLayout")
    layoutField.isAccessible = true

    val headerLayout = layoutField.get(presenter) as LinearLayout

    /*Set layout params on the HeaderLayout to match parent*/
    val params = headerLayout.layoutParams
    params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    headerLayout.layoutParams = params
}
```

**Where does this code execute?**

In your Activity's `onCreate` method. Here is the code needed to execute this:

```
    val navView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view_end)
    disableMenuScroll(navView)
    changeDrawerLayoutHeight(navView)
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to root tag (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout)...hope it helps.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

and try removing that android:overScrollMode from both root tag and navigationview